# How to convert this query to JPA Query

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, syntax-error

```
SELECT * 
FROM m_country_mk_py p,m_country_mk_sy s 
where p.id = s.mapping_id and s.lang_cd="en";
```

I'm not able to write same query in JPA, I'm facing some syntactical issue.

Comment: show your repository and entity class

Comment: What are your "syntactical issues"?

Comment: its resolved Thanks !!